# Unipolar transistor's transconductance/admittance

Tags: mosfet, fet, conductivity, formula-derivation

Unipolar transistor basic variable transconductance is commonly marked by:

[image]

It is commonly used in calculations where we need drain current, Ugs, rds(on), and similar.

I have also seen many equations for calculating upper variables but here mostly used variable is known as "conduction parameter" (unit: mA/V square).
It says (in the pdf file) that "K" should be given by manufacturer. But none datasheet till now had any value like this one.

Question: Do these two (transconductance & conduction parameter) have something in common? Can one replaced with another (probably not)? Are these equations with conduction parameter even used in practice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between transconductance (\$g_m\$) and the conduction parameter (\$K_n\$) may be found from the definition of \$g_m\$:

$$
g_m = \frac{\partial i_D}{\partial v_{GS}} = 2K_n\left(v_{GS}-V_{TN}\right) \\
\implies K_n=g_m/\left(2\left(v_{GS}-V_{TN}\right)\right)
$$

In other words, the conduction parameter may be found from the transconductance when given the [overdrive voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdrive_voltage) at which \$g_m\$ was measured.

It is also possible to find \$K_n\$ from \$g_m\$ when given the drain current at which \$g_m\$ was measured:

$$
g_m = 2K_n\left(v_{GS}-V_{TN}\right) = 2\sqrt{K_n}\sqrt{K_n\left(v_{GS}-V_{TN}\right)^2} = 2\sqrt{K_ni_D} \\
\implies K_n=g_m^2/\left(4i_D\right)
$$

In practice, the conduction parameter may be useful for [back-of-the-envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation), or approximate, calculations.

Reference: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-012-microelectronic-devices-and-circuits-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec11.pdf.  See slide 11-6 and apply definition \$K_n = W\mu_nC_{ox}/\left(2L\right)\$.

Comment: I hope these equations are true. Could you define the source of information written here?

Comment: You said "back-of-the-envelope calculations". What does that mean?

Comment: Updated response to address your questions.  Note that the same variable, \$K_n\$, is sometimes defined as \$W\mu_nC_{ox}/L\$.  As a result, you must be careful when applying formulas using \$K_n\$ to ensure the meaning of this variable is consistent.

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot to write that "n" near to it. "Kn" applies for NMOSFET and "Kp" for PMOSFET (n-electrons, p-holes).

Comment: I also forgot to write down which unipolar transistor I am reffering to: the equations from my question are reffering to MOSFET (as you can se Cox - cap), yours transconductance reffers to JFET if I'm right. Same transconductance applies for MOSFET except "K" is defined differently (look to my question).

Comment: My response refers to a MOSFET.